# APK files not install on my oppo a37

Tags: java, android-studio

I made a simple app by using android studio & build both signed and unsigned apk files. Then put those files into my oppo a37 device and try to install those. But both files gave following error message.
"Unable to install because of an error in the app APK. We recommend installing only certified apps from the play store."
I already checked these APKs by using android studio emulator and both works fine...
Please help me... Thank you...

Comment: You have to see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9807306/android-certificate-can-not-install-app-by-using-apk-file

Comment: did you found the solution @Prasad

Answer (score 0):

Go to Files in OPPO A37 phone and select APK icon. Then you can see your downloaded apk file. Click install:

[image]